PowerApps Unable to retrieve all SharePoint items into collection (+5000 items)
I have a SharePoint list with 5497 items. I would like to display all the items in a gallery however the code I am using to pull +5000 SharePoint list items is only getting 5470 items.
I am looping through the SharePoint list and adding 500 records to the collection for every iteration.
I have indexed the column PowerAppID in the SharePoint list.
Code here:
Set(firstRecord, First('Maintenance Work Order'));

Set(lastRecord,First(Sort('Maintenance Work Order', ID, SortOrder.Descending)));

Set(
    iterationsNo,
    RoundUp(
        (lastRecord.ID - firstRecord.ID) / 500 + 1,
        0
    )
);

ClearCollect(
    iterations,
    Sequence(
        iterationsNo,
        0
    )
);

Clear(colMaintenanceWO);
ForAll(
    iterations,
    With(
        {
            prevThreshold: Value(Value) * 500,
            nextThreshold: (Value(Value) + 1) * 500
        },
        If(
            lastRecord.ID > Value,
            Collect(
                colMaintenanceWO,
                Filter(
                    'Maintenance Work Order',
                    PowAppID > prevThreshold && PowAppID <= nextThreshold
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

